# Prevent RewriteCond from kicking in when trying to access a non-existing file from a folder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have the current setup in my `.htaccess` file:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
</ifModule>
```

It redirects any trafic to unexisting files or folders to `index.html`.

However, I would like to make an exception to the rule:
Any request made to `locales/non-existing.file` should return proper 404.

How can I do that?